# Can't install odoo 9.0 on my CentOS 6.7

Tags: python, centos, odoo, centos6

2 days and still cannot install Odoo on my Centos 6.7

-I have installed python 2.7
-I have installed PSQL
-Create a Odoo user
-When i installed Python i have this errors
http://puu.sh/l2uGc/bbf94c12da.png

When i run the command "yum install odoo" i have the following errors.

Errors:
Error: Package: odoo-9.0_20151029-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
           Requires: nodejs-clean-css
Error: Package: odoo-9.0_20151029-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.7
           Installed: python-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 (@base)
               python(abi) = 2.6

Comment: Error tells that required packages can't find in your system. So first install python packages or upgrade it with minimum supported and also others packages.

Answer (score 1):

### **install Python 2.7 and Python 3.3 on CentOS**

**Preparations – install prerequisites**

```
yum groupinstall "Development tools"
yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel db4-devel libpcap-devel xz-devel
```

- **Download, compile and install Python**

```ubuntu
# Python 2.7.6:
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tar.xz
tar xf Python-2.7.6.tar.xz
cd Python-2.7.6
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-unicode=ucs4 --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
make && make altinstall

# Python 3.3.5:
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.3.5/Python-3.3.5.tar.xz
tar xf Python-3.3.5.tar.xz
cd Python-3.3.5
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
make && make altinstall
```

- **Download and install Setuptools + pip**

```ubuntu
# First get the setup script for Setuptools:
wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py

# Then install it for Python 2.7 and/or Python 3.3:
python2.7 ez_setup.py
python3.3 ez_setup.py

# Now install pip using the newly installed setuptools:
easy_install-2.7 pip
easy_install-3.3 pip

# With pip installed you can now do things like this:
pip2.7 install [packagename]
pip2.7 install --upgrade [packagename]
pip2.7 uninstall [packagename]
```

### Install Clean CSS for odoo 9

Clean-css is a fast and efficient Node.js library for minifying CSS files.

According to tests it is one of the best available.
**What are the requirements?**

> Node.js 0.8.0+ (tested on CentOS, Ubuntu, OS X 10.6+, and Windows 7+)

**How to install clean-css?**

> npm install clean-css

How to upgrade clean-css from 1.x to 2.x?

Command-line interface (CLI)

> npm update clean-css

That's it!

For Reference Link :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-css-pre-2.1.0

http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the package "nodejs-clean-css" does not exist in EPEL6. But it does exist in EPEL7 and is a 'noarch'. I can get around the missing RPM dependency by issuing:

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/n/nodejs-clean-css-2.2.8-2.el7.noarch.rpm
```

Be aware though this is only a way to get around the missing dependency. In my experience there are a whole lot more things to be done before we can run Odoo on CentOS 6, mainly because Odoo installs for Python 2.7, but some dependencies are installed for Python 2.6.

With CentOS 7, it was smooth sailing, so I'd recommend using 7 if you have the option.